# Spring Data | Wrong query generation with sorting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a very strange problem.
I have some repository method that accepts `Pageable` as parameter. Here it is:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT product_name FROM product WHERE number = 1", 
countQuery = "SELECT COUNT (id) FROM product",
nativeQuery = true)
public List<String> getAllProducts(Pageable pageable);
```

When I use this method without sort inside of pageable everything is okay. Hibernate uses next query in this situation: `SELECT product_name FROM product WHERE number = 1 limit ?`.

But when I use sort inside of `Pageable` I get such a strange query: `SELECT product_name FROM product WHERE number = 1, product_name asc limit ?`.

Do you have any suggestions why spring puts `comma` instead of `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Try to use `pageable` directly in the query: `@Query(value = "SELECT product_name FROM product WHERE number = 1 ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}")`